# vim find claims to have many files but it is not

Tags: vim, vimrc

If I type `ls` in my directory, I get:

```
README.md lib       sdf.t     t.t       t1.t      t2.t      tt.t
```

I am in vim, and if i type: `:find *.t`, I get:`too many file names`

What is that happening?

If I print my vim path variable, I get:

```
.,/usr/include,,,**
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument to `:find` is supposed to be a single, exact, filename. `*.t` is expanded, so the command is `:find sdf.t t.t t1.t t2.t tt.t`, which does, in fact, have too many file names.

From [`:help :find`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Afind):

```
                                    :fin :find
:fin[d][!] [++opt] [+cmd] {file}
    Find {file} in 'path' and then :edit it.
    {not available when the +file_in_path feature was disabled at compile time}
```

Comment: I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XA2WjJbmmoM and the guy uses `*` to search, *no plugins*

Comment: That's an hour long video. Specify the time range where they do it, or provide a clipping.

Comment: Go to 10:36 to see how he applies it

Comment: And they use tab completion to expand `*cp.rb` to exactly one filename.

Comment: Oh yes, I have to hit tab, not enter. Thanks man

Comment: @jack Welcome to U/L. The best way to say thanks is to upvote and accept when you can.

Comment: @Sparhawk apparently i am not entitled to upvote because of my low reputation in the side.

Comment: @JackThomson I think you might be over the minimum now. :)